# Read one word line from a text file and store that in a variable in ant build file

Tags: ant, build.xml, ant-contrib

Please find below the sample ant file:-

```html
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
    <classpath>
    <pathelement location="../.ant/antcontrib.jar"/>
    </classpath>
    </taskdef>
    <loadfile property="file" srcfile="./dist/DB_Critical_Stub_Data.txt"/>
    <target name="read" depends="check-stub-status">
    <for param="line" list="${file}" delimiter="${line.separator}">
    <sequential>
    <antcall target="start-stub">
    </antcall>
    </sequential>
    </for>
    </target>
    <target name="start-stub">
    <startStub domain="..." environment="..." name="@{line}" securityToken="..." serverURL="..." dedicatedEngine="false"/>
    </target>
```

How do i enter value in name (under start-stub target) as long as the loop runs.In other words param= "line" should populate the value into name field everytime it reads one line from the text file. Since the text file has 15 lines and each line is a single word, so param="line" is anyways storing only each line word. and i want that to get passed to name field under start-stub target for entire loop so that all 15 line words are executed for name.

Answer (score 0):

i actually made it work using foreach and then passing "${line}" to name field.
For that i also removed antcall target and simply referred to target="start-stub" in the foreach statement.
It works now